# Undeclared type error when declaring interface in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, vivado

I'm trying to use an interface the following interface, which is declared in `<Project Directory>/OtterMCU.srcs/sources_1/new/BranchPredictor.sv` like so:

```
import Types::*;  // a package that provides the func3_t enum

interface BranchPredictor(
    input clk,
    input reset
);
    logic id_is_branch;
    func3_t id_branch_type;
    logic [31:0] id_pc;
    
    logic ex_branched;
    func3_t ex_branch_type;
    logic [31:0] ex_pc;
    
    logic should_branch;

    modport Predictor(
        input id_is_branch,
        input id_branch_type,
        input id_pc,
        
        input ex_branched,
        input ex_branch_type,
        input ex_pc,
        
        output should_branch
    );
    
    modport ID(
        output id_is_branch,
        output id_branch_type,
        output id_pc,
        input should_branch
    );
    
    modport EX(
        output ex_branched,
        output ex_branch_type,
        output ex_pc
    );
endinterface
```

When I use it in another module, Vivado gives an `undeclared type` error:

```
[Synth 8-3892] undeclared type 'BranchPredictor'  ["<redacted>/OtterMCU.srcs/sources_1/new/OTTER_MCU.sv":78]
```

Here's how it's used in a module (filename `<Project Directory>/OtterMCU.srcs/sources_1/new/OTTER_MCU.sv`):

```
module OTTER_MCU(/*...*/);
    // ...
    BranchPredictor ibpred();  // this is the offending line
    // ...

    IDStage id_stage(
        .predictor(ibpred.ID),  // this module uses one of the modports
        // ...
    );
    // ...
endmodule
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a Vivado specific problem. The order of compilation of modules and interfaces should not matter

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Changing the compile order to have the interfaces at the very top fixed this issue.